# Find regular grid cells intersecting arbitrary shaped quadrilateral

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js, geometry, computational-geometry

I need to find all indexes `[x, y]` for grid cells intersecting an arbitray shaped quadrilateral, defined by its corner coordinates;

- grid cells are tiles with `128 x 128 px`
- grid cells have an integer index between `[-nx, -ny]` and `[nx, ny]`
  (max extend is a square with `(2nx * 128) * (2ny * 128) px`)
- quadrilateral is defined by corner points, with coordinates `(qx, qy)` in pixel space given as `(tl, tr, br, bl)`
- This is integrated in a *three.js* scene:

  - corner points/coordinates are raycasted from camera on a base *THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry*

**How to get all intersecting tiles in a computationally efficient manner in JavaScript?**

For now I compute the perimeter tiles by traversing each quadrilateral edge using `mx + b` with the tile dimension (`128px`) as step; from there, I just add interior tile indexes row for row. But that´s somewhat clumsy, which might or might not be a coding skill issue. I am about to try using the *THREE.Raycaster* to get the perimeter tile indexes, but not sure how, yet.

I am seeking a better solution algorithm-wise; basic formulae, pseudo code, ideas, or definite solutions.

Comment: Consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016603/ also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634006/

Comment: @Mbo thx a lot! ...I just had a quick read, couldn't really grasp it fully yet: first thing I thought was if I can/should move from pixel space to index space (getting the tile index intersecting the corner points) and implement a direct lookup. or is that not really relevant here?

Comment: Work both in pixel coordinates and in `[column, row]` indexed cells - indexes of the next cell differ from current by one

Comment: @MBo indeed, the 'normalized' difference was what I was aiming at. thx again, I'll upvote both your linked answers; if you want, add one here, it seems to be the way to go, or I'll post my solution if I implemented one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To effectively find grid cells intersected by quad edges, you can use Woo and Amanatides grid traversal algorithm: article ["Fast Voxel Traversal Algorithm..."](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~amana/research/grid.pdf).
Practical implementation is in `grid traversal` section [here](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Raytracing_Topics_Techniques-Part_4_Spatial_Subdivisions.shtml)
Example:

[image]

For inner cells of convex quads: during edge traversal remember the leftmost cell in row for "right" edges, the rightmost cell for "left" edges, and fill horizontal gap  between them.